# What is the substitute for api/tests?

Tags: testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

SonarQube's web service `api/tests` is deprecated since SonarQube 5.2.

What would be a new good way to access this information?

Comment: you can check those things out in https://blog.sonarsource.com/
If you wont find your specific answer there you can approach the product managers-you find their profile there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api/tests` has been deprecated in 5.6, but it still [exists](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/tests).
The related tickets are [SONAR-7619](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7619) and [SONAR-7623](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7623), but we haven't add any description...

The reason of this deprecation is that this feature is not highly used (as most IDEs provide this information easily), and it does not bring a lot of value in SonarQube.
For the moment this API is still there but it may be removed in SonarQube 7.X.

Comment: I have a big legacy project with some tests failures in the backlog.
I would like to not break the build because of these errors, so i'm retrieving tests data to make a delta to advise only about new tests errors and publish in the pull requests comments.
For me, this api/tests still useful.

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed there's no more public web service to get coverage information. I've created a ticket to fix this : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10158

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: Now that we are in SonarQube 7.X, _api/tests_ is deprecated.
Do we have something else to use ? 
I want to see the status of my tests.

Comment: This feature is deprecated because it's no more implemented

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam So this is not possible to get the status of my tests with the SonarQube API in 2020 ?

Comment: Indeed, SonarQube is not a tool to get tests/coverage details information